# How to make a Else If statement more suitable, Xcode 4 iOS

Tags: xcode4, ios5, if-statement, tableview

I have a serious long else if statement which contains some links and some text.
This is for Xcode 4, iOS 5
**EDIT:**

```
stationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[stationList addObject:@"Q-dance Radio"];
[stationList addObject:@"The Voice"];
(ect ...)
[stationList sortUsingFunction:compareLetters context:nil];


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    
    if ([[stationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Q-dance Radio"])
    {
        [player pause];
        NSString *u = @"LINK TO Q DANCE RADIO";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [player play];
        
    }else if{
        [player pause];
        NSString *u = @"LINK TO THE VOICE";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [player play];
        
    } (ect ...)
```

How can I make this better or make it find the pressed one faster, so it doesn't need to run though the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an NSDictionary, and use the static strings as keys. I think you will get a good speedup from that. (The dictionary look-up probably hashes the input string that you use as a key.)

If you show more details, I can probably provide a more thorough answer. For example, you could even store the "do something here" code as a ^{} style block.

UPDATE
I am at my computer now and can refer to some real code for you. This is based on something I have already done. YOur code may be modified this way:

```
xxxList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
xxxListActionDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];  // add this line
[xxxList addObject:@"TEXT HERE"];
[xxxListActionDictionary 
    setObject:
          [[^{
              // DO SOMETHING HERE. THIS IS A BLOCK. SOME CODE TO BE EXECUTED.
          } copy] autorelease]    // I don't think you need autorelease if you use ARC
    forKey:@"TEXT HERE"];   // TEXT HERE is the same text put into the xxxListArray

ect.

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

// Here is where it gets efficient.
// The next three lines of code replace the entire if-else if...
void (^action)(void) = [xxxActionDictionary objectForKey:[[xxxList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  
if (action != nil) // you want to make sure the key is in the dictionary. may not be needed in your case.
    action();  // this executes the block
```

UPDATE

```
stationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[stationList addObject:@"Q-dance Radio"];
[stationListDictionary setObject:@"http://whateverQDanceRadioIs.com/folder/..." forKey:@"Q-dance Radio"];

[stationList addObject:@"The Voice"];
[stationListDictionary setObject:@"http://whateverTheVoiceIs.com/folder/..." forKey:@"Q-dance Radio"];

(ect ...)


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


[player pause];
NSString *u = [stationListDictionary objectForKey[stationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
[player play];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm at work atm, so i'll post some more detailed code when i come home, and will try the modification when i come home aswell.

Comment: I have updated my code so you can see some more specific what im doing.. Was think if it would be better to make a plist with all the links and the name of the station and play the link by the choosen ID or something ? or would you code still work here ?

Comment: You could do that. If looks like the URL string is the only difference in each if-block. You would read the plist into a NSDictionary, most likely. There are plenty of examples on how to do that. Or you can just hard code the dictionary contents. (That's what I would do, because I hate editing plists!)

Comment: Okay, ill leave the plist alone then :p So i can still use your code for the edit i made for me ?

Comment: I added an UPDATE that should help. My original answer was general purpose, but you don't need one quite that robust. But the NSDictionary is a good way to do what you want.

Comment: Been trying to change it, but i get this waring: http://cl.ly/0o3A0B3p2R0N312m2145 - When i run it, and go into the view where the list is being set/made, the Simulator crashed.. do you know whats wrong ? been trying to google it but cant really seem to find an answer :/

Comment: I'm sorry, Patrick. I should have said more clearly that `stationListDictionary` needs to be of type NSMutableDictionary. (I did say that in the first example, but not in the update.)

Comment: Aint it that when i did this: (NSMutableArray *stationList;
NSMutableDictionary* stationListDictionary;) and this: (stationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    stationListDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: 100];) or do i need to do something else ?

Comment: Well, I was looking at your picture on my iPhone, so I didn't see that you have too many square brackets. Look at my example again and put the square brackets where indicated in the setObject:forKey: method call.

Comment: Hmm tried that the first time, and didnt work... Well must have done something wrong, cause its working like a charm now :) Thank you very much !